# Display address on order review page

Tags: checkout, shipping-methods, payment-methods

We want to display the shipping and billing address and payment method details on the review page of the one page checkout. We use persistent checkout for this. I just want to show a summery of details what the user's selected or entered.

We currently have this:

Billing address:

```
<address><?php echo $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->format('html') ?></address>
```

Shipping address:

```
<?php if(!$this->getQuote()->isVirtual()): ?>
<address><?php echo $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->format('html') ?></address>
```

But this does only work if you refresh the page. The details do not load directly the first time. And I do not know how to display the payment method.

I'm also looking for the code to display the payment method.

Can anyone help me to display this instant on the review page?

Comment: Isn't this information on the standard Magento checkout sidebar? Did you remove that sidebar? Can you post screenshots of what you are seeing?

Comment: Sidebar is still available and also working. We want to keep this sidebar on every step, but we do want a summery on the review page on a more prominent place. That why we want to display these details on the review page. But we don't want to lose the sidebar

Comment: What phtml file are you putting your code into?

Comment: We used this file template/checkout/onepage/review.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this to show the information about the payment

```
$payment = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
```

This show me the title of the payment method. I don't know if is enough for what you want

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. '<address><?php $payment = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();?></address>
'

Comment: Can you do this separate? Like this <?php $payment = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle(); ?>
    <address><?php echo $payment; ?></address> . I don't know why but it matters

Comment: Tried that, but that brake down the checkout. :(

Comment: Is in the review in info.phtml, right?

Comment: Yes, info.phtml is the default Magento file. We did not change that. I only placed the code in review.phtml were we need it.

Comment: Could you add this line instead of the $payment = bla bla. Mage::Log('Checkout Session '. print_r(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->debug(),true)); and then see in var/log/system.log what is showing.

Comment: I get this message: Notice: Use of undefined constant ‌​ - assumed '‌​'  in /home/admin/domains/site.nl/public_html/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/template/checkout/onepage/review.phtml on line 52

and

ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /home/admin/domains/site.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 820

Comment: Then apparently is another thing. What's on line 51-53

Comment: On line 51-53 it was your code that I placed there. This error was only shown in system.log when adding the code you gave me.

Comment: Did you check without the code I gave you in system.log? Because is talking about an undefined constant, because obviusly I tested and it works

Comment: Yes without the code there was no error. Is there a way that I can contact you, so I can provide you the complete file?

Comment: Sure, send me the file to my mail arvizu90@gmail.com